# Change output XML values using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

i want my output XML to have different values. i have a table made.

lets say there are many students..

input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person>
        <lookuptable>
          <name first="Jen" ori="Jenny" />
          <name first="Sam" ori="Sammy" />
        </lookuptable>
    <Student>
        <Info Name="Jen" Age="20" Class="C" />
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Info Name="Sam" Age="21" Class="B" />

    </Student>

</Person>
```

required output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person>
        <lookuptable>
          <name first="Jen" ori="Jenny" />
          <name first="Sam" ori="Sammy" />
        </lookuptable>
    <Student>
        <Info Name="Jenny" Age="20" Class="C" />
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Info Name="Sammy" Age="21" Class="B" />

    </Student>

</Person>
```

how can i get `Jenny,Sammy`, etc from the lookuptable?? meaning each place `Jen` occurs it should use `Jenny` from table. im not sure how to write the XSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a key, use the identity transformation template plus a template for that attribute:

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="lookuptable/name" use="@first"/>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Student/Info/@Name">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('k1', .)/@ori"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>`?

Comment: @markdark, with XSLT 2.0 you can write `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>` and `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('k1', .)/@ori"/>`. As the question is tagged as `xslt-2.0` I have used features of that language version.

Comment: if i want to change age value to (ex:-twenty)(lets say there is another row for lookuptable with appropriate values).like above name, how do i add it to the xsl

Comment: Well define another key `<xsl:key name="k2" match="numbers/number" use="@value"/>` (assuming you have e.g. `<numbers><number value="20">twenty</number></numbers>`) and then add a template `<xsl:template match="Student/Info/@Age"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('k2', .)"/></xsl:template>`.